# Error while installing Scipy on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been facing this error while installing scipy module on Amazon Linux from [this link](http://dacamo76.com/blog/2012/12/07/installing-scikit-learn-on-amazon-ec2/):

```
(sk-learn)[root@ip-161-31-0-289 ec2-user]# pip install scipy
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

> /home/ec2-user/sk-learn/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2:
>   warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "
>   "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
>
> #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
>
> ^
>
> {standard input}: Assembler messages:
>
> {standard input}:374818: Warning: end of file not at end of a line;
>   newline inserted
>
> {standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing
>   .cfi_endproc directive
>
> g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
>
> Please submit a full bug report,
>
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>
> See http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla for instructions.
>
> error: Command "g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall
>   -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools -I/home/ec2-user/sk-learn/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
>   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.o" failed
>   with exit status 4
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /home/ec2-user/sk-learn/bin/python27 -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/home/ec2-user/sk-learn/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-SIVe3Y-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/sk-learn/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code
>   1 in /home/ec2-user/sk-learn/build/scipy

Comment: Solved it by increasing swap memory!

Comment: Please explain your solution by answering your own question. Add useful details to help other users who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

Increasing swap memory does the work

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=128M count=8
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

swapon -s will give you a usage summary